# "warping" an image on iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to find a way to do something similar to this on iOS:

[image]

Does anyone know a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a oneliner to do this, but you can use OpenGL to render a textured grid with quads, which has the texture coordinates equally distributed.

Exampe of 2x2 grid:

```
{0.0,1.0}        {0.33333,1.0}        {1.0,1.0}


{0.0,0.33333}    {0.33333,0.33333}    {1.0,0.33333}


{0.0,0.0}        {0.33333,0.0}        {1.0,0.0}
```

If you move shared vertices of adjacent quads (like in your example) while texture coords remain, you get a warp effect. You need a trivial vertex and fragment shader when using OpenGL ES, especially if you want to smoothen the warp effect, which is linearly interpolated per quad/triangle in its simple form.